# Selenium with Python, запуск тестов на выбор по параметру

Tags: python, selenium

Доброго времени суток.
Занимаюсь тестированием, пользуюсь  Селениумом и Пайтоном.

Встала необходимость записать все тесты в 1 файл и запускать скрипт с параметрами и чтобы, выполнялись, так сказать выбранные тесты.

Чую, что не хватает фундаментальных знаний, но гугление по конкретике, не привело  ни к ответу, ни к направлению где искать.

Сейчас тесты у меня разбиты по разным файлам, и в каждом захардкожено, куда заходить,  какй логин пароль и прочее.

```
class loginTest(unittest.TastCase):

def setUp(self):
    #открываю браузер и нужную страницу
def test_1(self):
    # логинюсь и выполняю набор кейсов
def test_2(self):
    # логинюсь и выполняю набор кейсов
def test_3(self):
    # логинюсь и выполняю набор кейсов
def test_4(self):
    # логинюсь и выполняю набор кейсов
def tearnDown(self):
    #Забираю из памяти теста лог, организую отчёт

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

То, что я хочу сделать выглядит макетно так, но как мне при запуске скрипта выбирать, запустить тест 1 и 4 или любой другой набор, идей нет. Кто сталкивался с таким, подскажите, рад буду даже ссылке, где можно почитать.

Comment: Использовать параметры из конфига пробовали? Задавать параметры в командной строке? ну или просить ввести параметры в самом приложении..

Comment: Дело в том, что когда объявляется класс иниттеста, селениум берёт и выполняет все тесты подряд, без разбора. И мне не известен механизм, как, куда и какой параметр передавать, чтобы запустить тот или иной тест отдельно.

Comment: Ну если я правильно понял, то с командной строки это делается так: `python -m unittest test_module.TestClass.test_method`. Это то что нужно?

Comment: Почти, Сейчас запускаю просто вот так (python testv1.py), а хочется, как-то так (python test.py -m 145), где числа, это номера тестов(может быть целиком писать, чтобы не  маяться с аасоциацией номера и теста)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как итог, нашёлся способ как запускать выбранные тесты. Делаем это через Suite, а  приклеить к функции параметр уже не сложно.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from selenium import webdriver
import unittest

class testsall (unittest.TestCase):

    def test_open_page(self):
        wd = webdriver.Firefox()
        wd.maximize_window()
        wd.implicitly_wait(60)
        wd.get("http://ukr.net")
       wd.close()

def suite():
    suite1 = unittest.TestSuite()
    suite1.addTest(testsall("test_open_page"))
    return suite1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open('/home/andrey/test.log','w') as logf:
            unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2, stream = logf).run(suite())
```

Answer (score 0):

перед test поставьте любой символ. Метод будет игнорироваться. Или закомментить. 
Пример: 
def _test_1(self):

Хотя может я не прав. Только 3 день как учу пайтон)
(поправьте меня если бред сгенерил:) )

Comment: Отвечайте на вопросы, в которых вы уверены.